# Lambda function not displaying on my aws console

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I have deployed my lambda function using serverless everything deploys without any issue but I could not find my lambda function on my aws console. I looked into specific region where I deployed.

Below command and result

sls deploy -s dev-polygon1 --region eu-central-1

Deploying sample-serverless to stage dev-polygon1 (eu-central-1)

✔ Service deployed to stack sample-serverless-dev-polygon1 (116s)

endpoint: ANY - [https://rndh58e0ae.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev-polygon1/{any+}](https://rndh58e0ae.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev-polygon1/%7Bany+%7D)
functions:
auth: sample-serverless-dev-polygon1-auth (22 MB)
proxyHandler: sample-serverless-dev-polygon1-proxyHandler (22 MB)

Comment: Use the awscli to list the Lambda functions for that region. Does it work?

Comment: Make sure you are in the correct region when using console.

Comment: Thanks for replys. Yes, @jarmod when I use list it is listing all the functions 
$ sls deploy list -s dev-polygon1 --region eu-central-1
2022-05-25 11:07:55 UTC
Timestamp: 1653476875385
Files:
  - compiled-cloudformation-template.json
  - sample-serverless.zip
  - serverless-state.json
2022-05-25 13:33:47 UTC
Timestamp: 1653485627915
Files:
  - compiled-cloudformation-template.json
  - sample-serverless.zip
  - serverless-state.json

$ sls deploy list functions -s dev-polygon1 --region eu-central-1
auth
  All versions: $LATEST, 1
proxyHandler
  All versions: $LATEST, 1

Comment: That's a different cli. You're using the sls cli and it probably uses internal state. That's why I proposed that you use the awscli. For example: `aws lambda list-functions --region eu-central-1 --query "Functions[].FunctionName"`. Also, obviously ensure you're in the correct region in the AWS console (you said that you were, but double-check) and force refresh the Lambda console.

Comment: Or you've accidentally deployed it to a different AWS account (not the one you're logged into the AWS console for). Check which credentials were used to deploy the app.

Comment: I have checked and logged into the same AWS account where I deployed but still I could not find my lambda functions :-(